# List running applications using NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Using NodeJS I want to get a list of open applications on Windows.

Something along the lines of:

```
exec("tasklist", function (error, stdout, stderr) {

    for(var i=0;i<stdout.length;i++)
    {
        if( stdout[i]['name'].indexOf('ll_') > -1 )
        {
            appList.push({'id':stdout[i]['id'],'name':stdout[i]['name']});
        }
    }

});
```

Where `appList` is an object of running applications with their ID and Name if they start with `ll_`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(I don't run Windows, so the following is untested)

First, install [`tasklist`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tasklist):

```
$ npm install tasklist
```

Then, use the following script:

```
var tasklist = require('tasklist');

tasklist(function(err, tasks) {
  if (err) throw err; // TODO: proper error handling
  var appList = tasks.filter(function(task) {
    return task.imageName.indexOf('ll_') === 0;
  }).map(function(task) {
    return {
      id   : task.pid, // XXX: is that the same as your `id`?
      name : task.imageName,
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped. However for future reference, it seems that the `tasklist` module has changed and needs to be used with promises instead of callbacks. So calling it would be `tasklist().then(function(tasks) { ..... });`

Answer (score 1):

Since stdout is just a large string, it needs parsing.

One way to do it would be:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('tasklist', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    var lines = stdout.trim().split("\n"); //split by line
    var processes = lines.slice(2); //remove the table headers
    var parsed = processes.map(function(process) {
        return process.match(/(.+?)[\s]+?(\d+)/); //match the process name and ID
    });
    var filtered = parsed.filter(function(process) {
        return /^ll_/.test(process[1]); //filter out process names starting with ll_
    });
    console.log(filtered);
});
```